# VECM, positive loading coefficients of EC terms?

Tags: cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I am looking at two very similar time series (correlation is about .997) - two commodity price series. 
Johansen coint. test indicates 1 coint. relationship for case 1 (no trend and no intercept) and no cointegration for other cases described by Johansen.

Lets denote the series A, B.
If I use the order of series A, B, then in the estimated VECM, the coint. vector is (1, -1.003722)'
The alpha coeff. for EC terms are 0.023158 (in equation for A) and 0.431335 (in eq. for B).

Now, if I estimate the VECM with reversed order, that is B, A (which should only influence the normalization of coint. vector) i get these results:
Coint. vector ( 1, -0.996066)' 
The alpha coeff. for EC terms are  -0.060448 (in equation for A) and -0.444057 (in eq. for B).

I wonder, why did the coefficients for EC terms changed their signs?
I was under the impression that EC terms should have negative coefficients in order to maintain the coint. relationship.

Data: [download CSV](http://wikisend.com/download/846884/data.csv)
Use from obs. 62 onwards
(a side question is that the cointegration results vary if you use all observations, or if you start from obs. 62)

Please, tell me if I understand it in the following example correctly.

```
Let's assume we observe: A=5,  B= 5.01;    

For order A, B:    
coint. vector: (1, -1.003722)';  
5 -1.003722*5.01 = -0.02864722;  
EC with loading in eq. for A:  0.023158 * -0.02864722 -> negative (A should go down?);   
EC with loading in eq. for B:  0.431335* -0.02864722 -> negative (B should go down?);  
for B, A:    
coint. vector: ( 1, -0.996066)';  
5.01-0.996066*5 = +0,02967;  
EC with loading in eq. for A:  -0.060448*+0,02967 -> negative (A should go down?);  
EC with loading in eq. for B:  -0.444057*0.02967 -> negative ( B should go down?);
```

Comment: This could be software-related. Can you share the platform/code & data that you are using for this analysis, so that we can replicate these numbers?

Comment: SW used was Eviews. Lag order 2

Answer (score 3):

Let the two cointegrating variables be $x$ and $y$.

The error correction term is $x-by$.

Consider equation 1 in the system (equation 1 or 2 does not matter, any one of them is enough to understand).

The error correction term with its loading is $a(x-by)$.

Now consider what happens when you switch the positions of $x$ and $y$ by renormalizing the cointegration vector. You use the following: $a(x-by)=-ba(y-\frac{1}{b}x)$ and get the new error correction term with its loading  $a'(y-b'x)$ where $a'=-ba$ and $b'=\frac{1}{b}$.

That means you actually *expect* the opposite sign, and it's not a mistake. Your reported coefficient values seem to agree with this.

Comment: OK, if we take coint. vector (1, -0.996), then let's assume value of A =5, B should be in equilibrium B=4.98.  If B is actually 5.01, then we have error in the long-run: e=B-Bhat= 5.01-4.98 = +0.03 ; If we want this relationship to be maintained, shouldn't the loading coefficient be negative, i.e. if multiplied by the positive error of 0.03, it should be reflected in the movement of B downwards (to the equilibirum value)?

Comment: I agree with you conceptually. On the other hand, doesn't my answer show how easily the sign gets reversed by just adopting an alternative representation of exactly the same object? If I have not made a mistake in the formulas above (have I?), it suggests that you look again into the estimation output and double-check whether it really does not make sense. Perhaps you will find out that the signs do match after all. Of course, I cannot guarantee you that since I cannot see the output :) It's just my guess.

Comment: So how is it with the loading coefficients? Can you comment on the example I provided?

Comment: @vladimir Perhaps Examples 7-9 here are helpful: http://www.math.ku.dk/~sjo/papers/OverviewPreprint.pdf

Comment: @hejseb, just checking, does my answer make sense?

Comment: Seems to make sense.